# Vue.JS Adding template/component to router.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

If somebody give me an answer how to import some templates to the route.js in Vue.js, I will be very grateful:)

This is my html

```html
 <head>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">
   <router-link to="/main">Main Page</router-link>
   <router-link to="/blog">Blog</router-link>
   <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
  
   <router-view></router-view>
 </div>
   
   <script src="/router.js"></script>  
 </body>
```

Next, I paste my router.js

```js
const Main = {template: '<p>Main page</p>'  }
const Blog = {template: '<h1>Blog</h1>' }
const Contact = {template: '<h1>Contact</h1>' }


const routes = [
 { path: '/main', component: Main },
 { path: '/blog', component: Blog },
 { path: '/contact', component: Contact }
]

const router = new VueRouter({ routes })

const routeapp = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

Everything works fine but I want to import template with own Styles, Js, css to each view.
How can I import it? 
I write here because nowhere in the Internet I found no information

/*!
 * Vue.js v2.6.10
 * (c) 2014-2019 Evan You
 * Released under the MIT License.
 */

/*!
  * vue-router v3.0.6
  * (c) 2019 Evan You
  * @license MIT
  */

Comment: Hi Dima, it maybe helpful, if you'd add information about the version of vuejs you're using.

Answer (score 0):

For each route, you mention a `path` and a `component`.

The component can be any Vue JS component. So, you can look at the [Vue JS library](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) documentation.

In the meantime, if you need an example of using Vue Router with a bit more well-defined components, you can refer to this tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-vue-router